# How can I work around Subversion's port being blocked when installing something with brew?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to follow the advice of a comment on this SO Q&A titled: [Use PPK file in Mac Terminal to connect to remote connection over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475069/use-ppk-file-in-mac-terminal-to-connect-to-remote-connection-over-ssh) that suggested you could install putty via an Subversion repository like so:

```
$ brew install putty --HEAD
```

When attempted I get this error:

```
$ brew install putty --HEAD
==> Cloning svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty
svn: E000060: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty'
svn: E000060: Can't connect to host 'svn.tartarus.org': Operation timed out
Error: Failed to download resource "putty"
Failure while executing: svn checkout -q --force svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty /Library/Caches/Homebrew/putty--svn-HEAD
```

**NOTE #1:** I believe the port used by Subversion is blocked by a corporate firewall.

**NOTE #2:** I'm ultimately trying to work around an issue with the version of putty that's included in Brew.

```
$ brew install putty
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/putty-0.63.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/putty-0.63.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring putty-0.63.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/putty/0.63: 11 files, 1.4M

$ puttygen privatekey.ppk -O private-openssh -o privatekey.pem
Enter passphrase to load key:
Assertion failed: (random_active), function random_byte, file ./unix/../sshrand.c, line 313.
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Run puttygen as `sudo` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to download the source from http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html then place it where Homebrew will find it then execute your brew command.

Read https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Tips-N'-Tricks.md#pre-downloading-a-file-for-a-formula for tips on how to do it.